# nested if statment in a while loop C

Tags: loops, if-statement, while-loop

So I have the following code and wondering why it won't be executed

```
int main() {
char select;
printf("Select q to quit\n");
while ((select = getchar()) != 'q') {
    if(select == 'a') {
        printf("You have not selected q\n");
        printf("Select q to quit\n");
    }
return 0;
}
```

So when select say 'a' for the character select, it doesn't go into the if statement. Why is that??

Comment: Have you tried printing `select` to make sure it is "a"?

Comment: Yes and it goes through the loop twice for some reason...I get it printing "aa"

Answer (score 0):

For me this code is Working on OSX. But you got the problem that it also quits if you press a. So simply move the "return 0"

```
int main() {
char select;
printf("Select q to quit\n");
while ((select = getchar()) != 'q') {
    if(select == 'a') {
        printf("You have not selected q\n");
        printf("Select q to quit\n");
    }
}
return 0;
```

Greetings :)

Comment: int main() {
char select;
printf("Select q to quit: ");
while ((select = getchar()) != 'q') {
    if(select != 'q') {
        printf("You have not selected q\n");
        printf("Select q to quit: ");
    }
}
return 0;
}

Comment: This is the updated...can you tell me why it is printing the if statement twice if select doesn't equal q?

Comment: I think it also gets the String Terminator "\0" Quick&Dirty Workaround: Ignore the String terminator.